# Use Twig in CSS

Tags: css, twig, silex

I would like to give style values using Twig variables.

*CSS*

```
.postit{
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #FFCB00;
    position;absolute;
}
```

*Twig*

```
{% for  user  in postits%}
    <div class="postit" style ="left:{{user.X}}px; top:{{user.Y}}px">

    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

no results divs don't move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in css.
Change `position;absolute;` to `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to this, ensure that your formatting of the HTML/TWIG code is standardised, just makes it easier to read and to spot issues like "Max P" stated.

```
{% for user in postits %}
    <div class="postit" style ="left:{{user.X}}px; top:{{user.Y}}px"></div>        
{% endfor %}
```

Make sure your spaces/tabs are all the same, as

```
{%endfor%}
```

can also cause issues!